# Regex to extract sequential number from user-defined id

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract the sequential number from a string ID which can be set in several formats. The string consist of 4 variables:

- Company code / char(3)
- Country / char(2)
- Year / char(4)
- Sequence nr / char(5), left padded with zeros

The format is configurable which means that we could have ids like:

US-XXX-201600001

2016-XXX-00001-US

00001-XXX-US/2016

... or any other defined format, but always with those 4 variables present.

The question is how to get the sequence number using regex (without zeros on the left) from whatever format I get, BUT considering that the year and the sequence nr can be together like "201600001". I need to get only the "1"

Edit: Due to the answers I'd like to clarify that the formats where only some possible examples. This is totally customizable by the user. There are no predefined formats. The only constant here are the 4 variables.
I know this might be complicated to solve with regex and I really appretiate all your answers. I will check your provided expression to check which one fits better.

Comment: Please be more precise on your expected input formats and the programing language in question.

Comment: It is C#. Is not possible to know the input format because that is user defined.

Comment: Can the years go into the previous century or are all 20XX? years. Is there a specific range to be expected? Which countries can be expected? Those limiters might provide a more concise pattern.

Comment: They are all 20XX. Countries can be all (ISO format). The dividers are totally customizable by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should capture all occurrences.  You'll need to run it in global mode to get all of the groups.  It will match even in cases where not all 4 groups are present, but you can simply check afterward to make sure it contains all 4 groups.

It doesn't actually enforce a format for the group ordering, just that each group is separated by a `-` or a `/`, except in the case of the year and sequence, which it allows to not be separated.

```
(?:(?<=^|-|\/)(?:(?P<cc>[A-Z]{2})|(?P<co>[A-Z]{3})|(?P<y>\d{4})|(?P<s>\d{5})|(?:(?P<y2>\d{4})(?P<cc2>\d{5})))(?=-|\/|$))+
```

https://regex101.com/r/uT2aU3/1

Comment: This pattern matches pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have some alternations in your regex and **extract the number programmatically**:

```
US-XXX-(?:201[0-9])(\d{5})|(?:201[0-9])-XXX-(\d{5})-US|(\d{5})-XXX-US/(?:201[0-9])
```

This will match all of your examples, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lI5aB4/1). However, you need to be more precise on your expected input formats, you'd then only need to loop over the captured groups.

Comment: As the formats are totally customizable, I guess that extracting the number programatically would be a simplier approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have to use more than one regex, for each variable, like this:

```
Company code / char(3) = \b[A-Z]{3}\b
Country / char(2) = \b[A-Z]{2}\b
Year / char(4) = \b[0-9]{4}(?=[0-9]{5})|\b[0-9]{4}\b
Sequence nr / char(5), left padded with zeros = [0-9]{5}\b
```

Comment: This might not be suitable for my scenario. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b\d{4}0*(\d{1,5})(?<=\b\d{9})\b|\b0*(\d{1,5})(?<=\b\d{5})\b/
```

### Split into two

When the year is first it is matched by the first part (1st set of brackets capture number):

```
\b\d{4}0*(\d{1,5})(?<=\b\d{9})\b
```

or without the year (2nd set of brackets capture number):

```
\b0*(\d{1,5})(?<=\b\d{5})\b
```

### Broken down:

- `\b` is a word break
- `\d` is a digit
- `(?<=X)` is a 'positive lookbehind': the previous matching text also matches the given regex `X`
- `\d{4}` means exactly four digits
- `\d{1,5}` means between one and five digits

https://regex101.com/r/rP2wZ4/1

Answer (score 0):

It is foolish not to insert *knowns* into the pattern....so why handicap the process?

Those are all countries which are known before the first pattern is ever run. How about a year that is in the 21st century?

This pattern lists the knowns as individual pattern matches per each line, then loads process the individual matches for each line into an entity for easy extraction thanks to named captures.

---

```
var datas = new List<string>()
{
"US-XXX-201600001",
"2016-YYY-86753-FR",
"09012-ZZZ-GB/2016"
};

var pattern = @"
(?<Country>US|FR|GB)  -- All Countries or'ed together.
          | 
(?<Year>20\d\d)       -- Only in the 21st century.
          |
(?<Company>XXX|YYY|ZZZ) -- All Company names are known and or'ed.
          |
(?<FullId>0{0,4}(?<Id>\d{1,5})) -- IDs have to have a number greater than 1.";


datas.Select(str =>  Regex.Matches(str, 
                                   pattern, 
                                  RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | 
                                  RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                          .OfType<Match>())
     .Select(mtchs => new Credentials(mtchs) );
```

**Result**

[image]

---

**Specialized Entity Class**

This class does some of the foot work extracting the data and loading it into the target property.

```
public class Credentials
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullId { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public Credentials(IEnumerable<Match> matches)
    {
        var properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToList();

        matches.ToList()
               .ForEach(mt => properties.ForEach(prp => AssignValid(prp, mt, prp.Name)));
    }

    public void AssignValid(PropertyInfo prop, Match mt, string name)
    {
        if (mt.Groups[name]?.Success ?? false)
            prop.SetValue(this, (mt.Groups[name].Value));
    }
}
```